# unable to install opencv in mac for python.. below is the error. else suggest a better way to install opencv

Tags: python, opencv

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/glog/lib/libglog.0.3.5.dylib
>   Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.3_1/lib/libopencv_sfm.3.4.dylib
>   Reason: image not found
> ```

above is the error - how to fix ?

Comment: Show us the command that had this error.

Comment: Your error seems to be referenced in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8652. I would recommend reinstalling opencv from either brew or pip3.

Comment: thsnk you John :)

Answer (score 0):

I searched for this problem and also got to [github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8652](http://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8652) where they recommended installing the missing library.
However, our error message references a different library -- glog: `brew install glog` worked for me!